# C++ wstringstream << NULL

Tags: c++, stream, null, wchar-t, wstring

I'm having an issue with wstringstream. When I'm doing this

```
    std::wstringstream ss;
    wchar_t* str = NULL;
    ss << str;
```

Application crashes with error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x53e347af (msvcr100d.dll) in stringstr.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

For example this works good:

```
ss << NULL;
wchar_t* str = L"smth";
ss << &str;
```

Not always str has value, it could be NULL sometimes and when it is NULL I would like to put 0 into stream. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's null, don't output a null `wchar_t` pointer:

```
( str ? ss << str : ss << 0 );
```

Note that this won't work:

```
ss << ( str ? str : 0 )
```

since the implicit conditional operator return type is a common type to both its expressions, so it would still return a null `wchar_t` pointer.

Comment: ahhhhh, I was trying `ss<<(!str ? 0 : str);` and it wasn't working

Comment: @user1112008: The implicit conditional operator return type is a common type to both its expressions, so in your case it would still return a null `wchar_t` pointer.

Comment: one more question, what if we are using templates? `template <typename type> std::string realToString(type real)` and we to check if `real` isn't NULL?

Comment: @user1112008: Assuming `type` is a pointer, is still the same check.

Comment: `error C2440: '?' : cannot convert from 'const std::wstring' to 'bool'` something is wrong

Comment: @user1112008: What's wrong is that `const std::wstring` is not a pointer. Use regular function overloading to have a different implementation for pointers than non-pointers: `template<typename type> std::string realToString(type real)` for the regular case, and `template<typename type> std::string realToString(type* real)` for pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Check before you output to the stringstream (as already suggested)

```
if (str == NULL) {
    ss << 0;
} else {
    ss << str;
}
```